# How to pivot multiple columns without aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I use SqlServer and i have to admit that i'm not realy good with it ...
This might be and easy question for the advanced users (I hope)

I have two tables which look like this

First table (ID isn't the primary key)

```
ID      IdCust   Ref
1       300      123
1       300      124
2       302      345
```

And the second (ID isn't the primary key)

```
ID     Ref      Code    Price
1      123      A       10
1      123      Y       15
2      124      A       14
3      345      C       18
```

In the second table, the column "Ref" is the foreign key of "Ref" in the first table

I'm trying to produce the following output:

[image: The result what i want]

[EDIT]
The column "Stock", "Code" and "Price" can have x values, so I don't know it, in advance...

I tried so many things like "PIVOT" but it didn't give me the right result, so i hope someone can solve my problem ...

Comment: Indeed you need PIVOT. It would be interesting to see the code you tried. Question: How many line will the same Ref have max. at second table? two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `row_number()` function and do the *conditional* aggregation :

```
select id, IdCust, Ref,
       max(case when Seq = 1 then stock end) as [Stock A], -- second table *id*
       max(case when Seq = 1 then code end) as [Code 1],
       max(case when Seq = 1 then price end) as [Price1],
       max(case when Seq = 2 then stock end) as [Stock B], -- second table *id*
       max(case when Seq = 2 then code end) as [Code 2],
       max(case when Seq = 2 then price end) as [Price2]
from (select f.*, s.Id Stock, s.Code, s.Price,
             row_number() over (partition by f.Ref order by s.id) as Seq
     from first f
     inner join second s on s.Ref = f.Ref 
     ) t
group by id, IdCust, Ref;
```

However, *this* would go with *known* values else you would need go with *dynamic* solution for that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer which is realy interesting

But, as you said, i need to use dynamic solution, because I can't know in advance the number of "Seq"

Do you have any idea, for the dynamic solution ?

Answer (score 3):

@YogeshSharma's provided an excellent answer.

Here's the same done using `Pivot`; [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/48ede/7).

Functionally there's no difference between the two answers.  However, Yogesh's solution's simpler to understand, and performs better; so personally I'd opt for that... I included this answer only because you mention PIVOT in the question:

```
select ft.Id
, ft.IdCust
, ft.Ref
, x.Stock1
, x.Code1
, x.Price1
, x.Stock2
, x.Code2
, x.Price2
from FirstTable ft
left outer join (
  select Ref
  , max([Stock1]) Stock1
  , max([Stock2]) Stock2
  , max([Code1]) Code1
  , max([Code2]) Code2
  , max([Price1]) Price1
  , max([Price2]) Price2
  from
  (
    select Ref
    , Id Stock
    , Code
    , Price
    , ('Stock' + cast(Row_Number() over (partition by Ref order by Id, Code) as nvarchar)) StockLineNo
    , ('Code' + cast(Row_Number() over (partition by Ref order by Id, Code) as nvarchar)) CodeLineNo
    , ('Price' + cast(Row_Number() over (partition by Ref order by Id, Code) as nvarchar)) PriceLineNo
    from SecondTable
  ) st
  pivot (max(Stock) for StockLineNo in ([Stock1],[Stock2])) pvtStock
  pivot (max(Code) for CodeLineNo in ([Code1],[Code2])) pvtCode
  pivot (max(Price) for PriceLineNo in ([Price1],[Price2])) pvtPrice
  Group by Ref
) x
on x.Ref = ft.Ref
order by ft.Ref
```

Like Yogesh's solution, this will only handle as many columns as you specify; it won't dynamically alter the number of columns to match the data.  For that you'd need to do dynamic SQL.  However; if you need to do that, it's more likely you're attempting to solve the problem in the wrong way... so consider your design / determine if you really need additional columns per result rather than additional rows / some alternate approach...

---

Here's a Dynamic SQL implementation based on @YogeshSharma's answer: [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fb69225ba448a67f7f09a0c0a8575a88)

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'select id, IdCust, Ref'
select @sql = @sql + '
        ,max(case when Seq = 1 then stock end) as [Stock' + rowNumVarchar + '] 
        ,max(case when Seq = 1 then code end) as [Code' + rowNumVarchar + ']
        ,max(case when Seq = 1 then price end) as [Price' + rowNumVarchar + ']
'
from 
(
    select distinct cast(row_number() over (partition by ref order by ref) as nvarchar) rowNumVarchar
    from second s
) z
set @sql = @sql + '
    from (select f.*, s.Id Stock, s.Code, s.Price,
                 row_number() over (partition by f.Ref order by s.id) as Seq
         from first f
         inner join second s on s.Ref = f.Ref 
         ) t
    group by id, IdCust, Ref;
'
print @sql --see what the SQL produced is
exec (@sql)
```

(Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/40bba7/1) link for this one; but it's not working despite the SQL being valid

Comment: Thank you for your solution !

But yeah, the problem (sorry I forget to write this in my first post) is this the same because I have to make dynamix SQL ...

Unfortunately I have to add it per columns :/

What do you mean with "additional rows" ? Do you have an additional  solution for dynamic SQL ?

Comment: No worries, dynamic SQL created... but as mentioned normally needing to add columns at runtime is a sign that something's wrong with the design.  By `addtional rows` I simply mean that for 3 entries with the same `REF` value your current solution requires you to add 3 sets of stock, code & price columns; whereas you could have those same results show by having the fixed number of columns (i.e. one price column, one code, and one stock), and having one row per result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried both answer and that didn't work ... The problem come from ... me :/ I made a huge misstake, i do not work on sql Server but on mySql ... realy sorry for the wrong post. I'm gonna edit my post.   I tried your solution and edit some informations and I have an error line 25 "('Stock' + cast(Row_Number() over (partition by Ref order by Id, Code) as nvarchar)) StockLineNo"
Error : [...] right syntax to use near 'over (partition by Ref order by Id, Code) as nvarchar)) StockLineNo , ('Code' at line 25). Do you have a suggestion ?

Comment: No worries.  I'm not that familiar with the more advanced bits of MySQL... I'd suggest you're best off making a new post with the correct tags and pointing to this question saying "I'm trying to create dynamic SQL in MySQL to achieve the same as this T-SQL", and marking Yogesh's answer above as the accepted answer for this post as Yogesh resolved your original question with the best solution.

Comment: FYI: This post explains how to simulate `row_number` in MySQL, so may be helpful if you wanted to give it a go yourself first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1895127/361842

Comment: Not a bad idea :) I cannot upvote your both answer, but i will follow your suggestion. Thank you for your time and for your answer ;)